# C++ issue concerning inheritance and casting

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, overloading

I am currently working on an amateur physic engine for a school project but I'm stuck because of a C++ issue. The setting is the following :

I have three different classes :

- RigidBody (abstract)
- Sphere (inherits from RigidBody)
- CustomRigidBody (inherits from RigidBody and represents a polyhedra)

I need to check if a collision occurs between a pair of bodies with two eponymous methods. One is used to check for a contact with a Sphere whereas the other is used to check for a contact with a CustomRigidBody. There are several possible scenarii (Sphere/Sphere collision, Sphere/Custom collision, etc...) so these two methods are defined within all of these classes.

In RigidBody, they are abstract :

```
virtual bool isCollidingWith(Sphere* s_p) = 0;
virtual bool isCollidingWith(CustomRigidBody* rb_p) = 0;
```

But not in Sphere :

```
bool isCollidingWith(Sphere* s_p);
bool isCollidingWith(CustomRigidBody* rb_p);
```

Nor in CustomRigidBody :

```
bool isCollidingWith(Sphere* s_p);
bool isCollidingWith(CustomRigidBody* rb_p);
```

In my main program, I have a `std::vector<RigidBody*>` containing pointers to RigidBodies (the superclass) and I need to check for collisions between objects by pair by calling something like :

```
for(int i = 1; i < this->bodies_p.size(); ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        if(this->bodies_p[i]->isCollidingWith(this->bodies_p[j]))
            std::cout << " COLLISION BETWEEN " << i << " AND " << j << std::endl;
```

I was under the impression that C++ would be OK with that but I get the following error message :

```
Engine.cc:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘RigidBody::isCollidingWith(RigidBody*&)’
RigidBody.h:53: note: candidates are: virtual bool RigidBody::isCollidingWith(Sphere*)
RigidBody.h:54: note:                 virtual bool        RigidBody::isCollidingWith(CustomRigidBody*)
```

My guess is that it has to do with the fact that the vector of bodies contains pointers to RigidBodies and they are not automatically casted to Sphere* or CustomRigidBody* but I don't know how to fix the issue.

Thank you for your assistance ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is solved by [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).  Essentially, you need to add another overload to `RigidBody` and its derived classes:

```
bool isCollidingWith(RigidBody* rb_p) = 0;
```

In the derived classes, e.g. `Sphere`, the implementation would look like:

```
bool Sphere::isCollidingWith(RigidBody* rb_p)
{
    return rb_p->isCollidingWith(this);
}
```

This works because the first time `isCollidingWith` is called (in your loop), the version of `isCollidingWith(RigidBody*)` from the correct derived class is called (via the virtual method).  Then, in `Sphere::isCollidingWith(RigidBody*)`, the correct derived class is used via the virtual method.  However, this time, `this` is a `Sphere*`, so the overload that is called is the `isCollidingWith(Sphere*)` version.

In other words:

1. In your loop:

   ```
   this->bodies_p[i]->isCollidingWith(this->bodies_p[j])
   ```

   will call either `Sphere::isCollidingWith(RigidBody*)` or `CustomRigidBody::isCollidingWith(RigidBody*)`, depending on the actual type of `bodies_p[i]`.  Assuming it is a `Sphere`, then we get
2. In `Sphere::isCollidingWith(RigidBody* rb_p)`:

   ```
   return rb_p->isCollidingWith(this);
   ```

   which calls either `Sphere::isCollidingWith(Sphere*)` or `CustomRigidBody::isCollidingWith(Sphere*)`, depending on the actual type of `rb_p`.

Comment: Nice 'trick'. Even stopped adding my answer, since this is much better then my solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation! The Wikipedia link you pasted even quotes physic simulation as one of the characteric situations to use double dispatch =D

Comment: @RedX: same here. God, I love StackOverflow. :D